# typescript add missing fields to a type that should have them

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a helper function for my database code.  Every table in the database has some common fields (pk, creation date, etc) that is implemented as a common interface which the other table's interfaces extend. I want to make a function that automatically adds those common properties to an object and returns the new object, but typescript complains about subtype assignment in a way I can't understand...

```
Type '{ id: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "id">>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{ id: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "id">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 
'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Common'
```

I've made a minimal code example on the TS playground to reproduce it.  For a given type, T which extends the Common base interface, I want to take in an object containing all the required fields of T, *except* those that are in Common, and then return the object with the added fields.

```
interface Common {
    id: string;
}

interface Table extends Common {
    data: string;
}

function makeDbEntry<T extends Common>(initial: Omit<T, 'id'>): T {
    const common: Common = {
        id: 'random string',
    };
    const ret: T = {
        ...common,
        ...initial,
    };
    return ret;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=49&pln=9&pc=62#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZWAYQPYFssbMAbwChhTQATALmAGcIZwBzAbiIF8ijxp5lUAVBACMANqigAPaGHI102XPmJlg5BBATU6DMC3ac4AVzBIIIPMCwIA1lAAiQgKKQYATwA8-YJOmz5OPAA+AApwEDMEEWoAeSxwzwAaYAByEHJkwIBKai9lMiQ8OmACgLBqTFLgAF5CEhUyNOpkmAQZbFp6JmSEutI2VhUCsCKYKAgc6tr6sgA6OZLFHunSOZmwiJElsn7e4FGIQxh8fdY2IA)

There doesn't seem to be any way to remove the fields from T without explicitly listing their fields (can't do 'T minus Common'), as far as I can tell...

Comment: `Omit` can't be fully resolved for a type parameter. Just use a type assertion

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir can you give an example?  Not sure what you mean.  Even if, for testing purposes, I replace the Omit with { data: string }, I still get the error

Comment: It doesn't fix your error, but you can do `Omit<T, keyof Common>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional types can't be fully resolved if they contain type parameters. This means that, at least for this use case, `Omit<T, 'id'>` is basically opaque, TS can't look inside what this type is, it is just a type which is distinct from `T`.

When you do the spread operation, TS correctly understands that this will generate an intersection  between common and `Omit<T, 'id'>` (`{ id: string; } & Omit<T, 'id'>`). But since `Omit` is as I have said opaque, no further simplification of this type can be done. Even though to the human this is trivially resolvable to `T`, typescript does not know how to simplify this type.

If you replace `T` with a concrete type, then ts can easily understand that for example `{ id: string; } & Omit<Table, 'id'>` is the same as `Table`, so this works:

```
function makeDbEntryForTable(initial: Omit<Table, 'id'>): Table {
    const common: Common = {
        id: 'random string',
    };
    const ret: Table = {
        ...common,
        ...initial,
    };
    return ret;
}
```

For the generic version, your best bet, as in most cases where the dev has a better understanding than the compiler, is to use a type assertion:

```
function makeDbEntry<T extends Common>(initial: Omit<T, 'id'>): T {
    const common: Common = {
        id: 'random string',
    };
    const ret: T = {
        ...common,
        ...initial,
    } as T;
    return ret;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZWAYQPYFssbMAbwChhTQATALmAGcIZwBzAbiIF8ijxp5lUAVBACMANqigAPaGHI102XPmJlg5BBATU6DMC3ac4AVzBIIIPMCwIA1lAAiQgKKQYATwA8-YJOmz5OPAA+AApwEDMEEWoAeSxwzwAaYAByEHJkwIBKai9lMiQ8OmACgLBqTFLgAF5CEhUyNOpkmAQZbFp6JmSEutI2VhUCsCKYKAgc6tr6sgA6OZLFHunSOZmwiJElsjZgBDl+AbJRiEMYfGPWDiIAemvgWPDVDCg5MAwIYAALBAA3VARgBBXAAHVDAhAtLBjWBJCCfEByGgYYAAAweEE8wjESVS6UCKNAciMIhErmA1jAAHc8EQjCYzBYrLYHM56K4AGIYGCCURQUJgcIgSIxOIYnnYlJpDLZYDi1B5UhDIoLPDlBQWGoK+qNFItNpYDo6RjdXrAfqmpUfY45LGoTWmlSrFVgLbTVbrIWbU3mlTHU7nMaXIA)

Comment: found this, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884.  So the not resolving opaque types like this is an open Typescript issue...

Comment: @zacaj Yeah, it's a current limitation, I would not expect it to change in the near future though